# Is it possible to make a tcp connection (server-client) with shared hosting?

Tags: java, android, http, tcp, webserver

I would like to know if it is possible to make a TCP connection between my mobile app and a site on a shared hosting server. Instead of checking the server every interval of time (30 seconds), I would like to make it more professional, getting the message to my mobile without refreshing. Is it possible on a shared hosting or should I have a dedicated server?

I cannot provide codes. I just need an idea on how to start, I'm searching for the first key.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can get a dedicated IP address in the shared hosting, you should be able to float a TCP server there.  Please note that, you can float a TCP server even when you IP is shared, but then there is no guarantee on the port number -- some other tenant on that shared IP can also end up using the same port number and that might be an issue. Can your provider allocate you a specific port (or ports) -- if so, then you can do without having a dedicated IP address. Here is a good read: https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/426

Once you have a connection, it is a matter of sending updates periodically via the socket to refresh it instead of a manual refresh.